# MVC app stops after SendAsync to an API - The same code runs fine in Console App though

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dotnet-httpclient

I built a simple Console Application to test the connection to an API. Calling the connection method from Console App Main works fine. I get a response with an access-token.

I though that I just could implement the same method/code to an MVC-project and add the method within the `HomeController`, then call the method from any `ActionResult`, getting the access-token and then put it in a `ViewBag` to display it in a view (just for testing), but it doesn't work in the MVC-project.

If I run the debugger, it seems like the app hangs when `SendAsync` is executed in the method. The console gives this output:

> Application Insights Telemetry (unconfigured):
> {"name":"Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Dev.RemoteDependency","time":"2017-04-08T09:26:32.4945663Z","tags":{"ai.internal.sdkVersion":"rddf:2.2.0-738","ai.internal.nodeName":"XXXXXX","ai.cloud.roleInstance":"XXXXXXXX"},"data":{"baseType":"RemoteDependencyData","baseData":{"ver":2,"name":"/token","id":"XXXXXXXXX=","data":"https://api.vasttrafik.se/token","duration":"00:00:00.2810000","resultCode":"200","success":true,"type":"Http","target":"api.vasttrafik.se","properties":{"DeveloperMode":"true"}}}}
> The thread 0x1f68 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

What can I do to make the API-call / response work in the MVC-application?
My knowledge in the area is ridiculously low, but I really want to understand whats going on here.

**MVC project**

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
       
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        string token = PostRequest().Result;
        ViewBag.Token = token;
        
        return View();
    }

    async static Task<string> PostRequest()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://api.vasttrafik.se");
        var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "/token");
        // Key                            // Secret
        string credentials = "xxxxxxxxxoVS5xDrcO6qZsAp0a" + ":" + "xxxxxxxxhn0STj1w4asDwixdMa";
        var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(credentials);
        //Key and secret encoded
        string encodedCrentedials = Convert.ToBase64String(plainTextBytes);

        //Console.WriteLine(encodedCrentedials);

        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic", encodedCrentedials);

        var formData = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
        formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
        formData.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("scope", "xxxxxxxxw0oVS5xDrcO6qZsAp0a"));

        request.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(formData);
// This is where the app hangs....
        var response = await client.SendAsync(request);
        var mycontentres = await response.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
        var responseBody = Encoding.Default.GetString(mycontentres);

        //Console.WriteLine(responseBody);

        JavaScriptSerializer seri = new JavaScriptSerializer();

        dynamic data = JObject.Parse(responseBody);

        string tok = data.access_token;
        return tok;
    }
}
```

Comment: I "solved" this by changing the method not to be async, just a "public string PostRequest()".

Is this a bad solution? Would async be better for this kind of actions?

Answer (score 0):

[Don't block on async code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html):

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
{
  string token = await PostRequest();
  ViewBag.Token = token;

  return View();
}
```